# how to display a popup text when mouse is over a button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

for the below posted code, it is part of a template of an angular .ts file.
i managed to print text on the browser's console when the mouse is over or hover or enters the button area.
but i want to when the mouse is over or hovers over the button is to display a text as pop-up that appears in when over and disappears when the mouse leaves the buttom area

**code**:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon"   (click)="editTopography()" (mouseover)="onMouseover($event)" data-tooltip="text"> <clr-icon shape="pencil"></clr-icon></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/title)

```html
<button title="I appear on hover">Hover me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tooltip in pure css with help of `::after` **Pseudo-Element**.

```css
button{
  position: relative;
}
button::after{
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 300ms;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(15px);
}
button:hover::after{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<button data-title="I appear on hover">Hover me!</button>
```